# iOS7 merged statusbar and toolbar

Tags: ios, uitoolbar, ios7, uistatusbar

How do I create a toolbar that is merged with the status bar at the top in iOS7, like in the Safari app? This can be easily achieved using a UINavigationBar, however, an UIToolbar is needed.

[image: Safari's toolbar in iOS 7]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that you've already got a toolbar at the top, but that it's 44pts high instead of 64pts as you'd like.  If that's the case, then you need to set the bar's `barPosition` property to `UIBarPositionTopAttached`.

Comment: Nice, but how do I do this in storyboards or programatically?

Answer (score 0):

This is only for `UINavigationController` and its `UINavigationBar`.

You should use a navigation controller even if you're not pushing/popping.

Answer (score 0):

Create a properly sized background image for the Toolbar.  Check out Apple's iOS7 UI Transition Guide for all the details.